# How to display data stored in SQLite database using List<>

Tags: android, list, android-layout, android-fragments, android-sqlite

Actually, my problem is that when I had done it with Room the Id which I was entering were coming in a sequence like:100,101 and so on, but on the other hand when I am using SQLite user ids are appearing as they are entered i.e., not in sequence like: 100,101,99,98. Please help me out.

Comment: Your question is broad. You should first learn about `RecyclerView` and database operations. Using `Room` database library will be a better approach.

Comment: I have done it using Room but I want to do it using SQLite

Comment: Using room you can get data in List.

Comment: Actually, my problem is that when I had done it with Room the Id which I was entering were coming in a sequence like:100,101 and so on, but on the other hand when I am using SQLite user ids are appearing as they are entered i.e., not in sequence like: 100,101,99,98. Please help me out. @SagarChapagain

Comment: You had included tags related to android-layout, android-fragments, sqlite, list, etc. but there is not single piece of information on what you are trying to do, what have you done till now, and what is the problem you faced. Please edit your question first.

Comment: Try Querying up the result like "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY ID".

Comment: It's working, but I am hot giving any ORDER BY clause in Room Persistence still it is showing the result in ascending order but in SQLite database data is appearing as it was entered like 100,99,101 i.e., there is no particular order@GowthamKK